# overall count not as expected in grafana dashboard

Tags: graphite, grafana

i have the following singlestat for capturing the overall count of "lookups".
Whe I select a date range e.g. Nov 25, 2015 10:49:23 to Nov 25, 2015 19:31:18 I get a value of 82(see image)

[image]

I am using the following metric:

[image]

When I zoom out to get a greater date range e.g. Nov 24, 2015 08:54:39 to Nov 25, 2015 19:42:18 the value of 82 "Lookups" goes to 41. 
See image:

[image]

I was expecting the count to remain at 82 as I am getting an overall count.
I know the issue is not to do with graphite or grafana, so what am I doing wrong?

Update 
This is my storage-aggregation.conf

```
[min]
pattern = \.lower$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = min

[max]
pattern = \.upper(_\d+)?$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = max

[sum]
pattern = \.sum$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[count]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[count_legacy]
pattern = ^stats_counts.*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[default_average]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0.3
aggregationMethod = average
```

Comment: What does the underlying series for the singlestat look like, and how is the singlestat calculated?  If the aggregation method (as specified by storage-aggregation.conf) is 'average' (which is also the default), peaks will be smoothed out, so a singlestat panel using "max" will show a lower value for longer timeframes.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I Have updated question with details on storage-aggregation.conf configuration. Not sure what you mean for "underlying series for the singlestat look like" - is this whaat is returned from making the "render" call to graphite?

Comment: Did you select 'sum' as aggregation function for the "value" option in http://docs.grafana.org/reference/singlestat/ ?

Comment: A singlestat is still based on a metric expression, though it displays one value instead of graphing the series.  It's possible for a singlestat series to be aggregated twice -- once by the Graphite server, as determined by the timeperiod sent by Grafana and by storage-aggregation.conf, and again by Grafana, based on the "Value" pulldown in the "Options" tab for the singlestat.  First confirm that the series Grafana is using to derive the singlestat is what you want; try creating first as a graph panel, or use your browser's "Network" panel to look at the metric request being sent to graphite.

Comment: Have you managed to configure it, @Noel?